# jquery unselecting all checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="SomeID">

  <input type="checkbox" class="SomeClass">
  <input type="checkbox" class="SomeClass">
  <input type="checkbox" class="SomeClass">

</div>
```

I want to unselect all the checkboxes that are of type SomeClass.

```
  $('#SomeID .SomeClass').each(function () {
     $(this)....
  });
```

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'd use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$('#SomeID .SomeClass').prop('checked', false);
```

If you're in a version of jQuery pre 1.6, you'd use:

```
$('#SomeID .SomeClass').each(function () {
    this.checked = false;
});
```

---

### Don't use `attr` or `removeAttr` for changing `:checked` state!

<sup>There is a difference between changing the checked property on the element and changing the checked attribute, it's subtle, but worth mentioning.</sup>

If you change the attribute value, and the user resets the form, the "reset" state will be pulled from whether the `[checked]` attribute exists. If you've been adding/removing the `[checked]` attribute, you will have lost the original state of the checkbox.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/p3GN2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".SomeClass").prop('checked', false);
```