# jquery getting index of selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML like this:

```
<div id="Myclass">

 <div class="Wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" class="SomeCheckboxClass">
    <input type="checkbox" class="SomeCheckboxClass">
    <input type="checkbox" class="SomeCheckboxClass">
 </div>

 <div class="Wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" class="SomeCheckboxClass">
    <input type="checkbox" class="SomeCheckboxClass">
    <input type="checkbox" class="SomeCheckboxClass">
 </div>

</div>
```

I want to find the index of a the selected textbox, if any.

For now, I wrote this:

```
$('#MyClass .Wrapper').each(function () {

    Index = 0;

    $(this).find('.SomeCheckboxClass').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            Index = $(this).index();
        }
    });

    SomeFunction(Index);
});
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What if more than one checkbox is checked?

Comment: the `[checked]` attribute isn't the indicator of whether a checkbox is checked, [also i think my answer to this question is relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915665/jquery-unselecting-all-checkboxes/10915711#10915711).

Comment: @JamesAllardice: only one checkbox is selected; I've got another function that makes sure of that.

Comment: @frenchie, why are you using checkboxes if only one can be selected? You should be using radio buttons.

Comment: @zzzzBov: because I want to be able to unselect them all. With radio buttons, once you select one, you can't revert to the state "none selected".

Comment: @frenchie, [yes you can](http://jsfiddle.net/vmA8t/).

Comment: @zzzzBov: you're thinking like you're just a programmer. Look at the user interface you're suggesting again: you need to click reset to reset the controls. With textboxes, you just check and uncheck: much better design. I have 3 checkboxes per Wrapper, you check one it unchecks the others and you uncheck the one that's selected and it resets the form. No need for the reset element.

Comment: @frenchie, I'm actually thinking about the accessibility. There is a major difference in how interface elements react, and you're trying to turn a checkbox into a radio button. Without more domain knowledge to what problem you're trying to solve, all I can tell you is that you're using the wrong element. If you wanted to toggle the radio button off, add a click handler to uncheck a radio button if it's checked (toggle on/off). Better yet, write up a question on [ux.se].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.map`: http://jsfiddle.net/p4nD7/1/.

```
$("#Myclass .Wrapper :checkbox:checked").map(function() {
  return $(this).index();  // index in parent
}).each(function() {
  "use strict";  // no object for `this` but just the primitive value
  SomeFunction(this);
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more why are you using "use strict" in that function? I know it's out of the scope of the question, but I can't understand it.

Comment: @Chango: Basicaly, without that, it's always an object rather than a primitive value. E.g. 2 becomes new Number(2) automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#Myclass .Wrapper').each(function() {
    var Index = $('.SomeCheckboxClass:checked', this).index();
    SomeFunction(Index);
});
```

**[​DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/159/)**

You can also use `map()`

```
$('#Myclass .Wrapper').map(function() {
    var Index = $('.SomeCheckboxClass:checked', this).index();
    SomeFunction(Index);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/158/)**

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this:

```
$('.checkbox').click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('checked')) {
        SomeFunction($(this).index());
    }
});
```