# How to disable all the checkboxes inside jquery multiselect

Tags: jquery, multi-select

In jQuery, how does one go about disabling all the  checked boxes inside multiselect.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915665/jquery-unselecting-all-checkboxes

Comment: Checked boxes inside multiselect? What exactly is that?

Comment: http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#basic.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", "disabled")
```

This works fine but it might be work thinking about limiting the operation to a given part of the page. Unchecking all boxes might be fine now but later you may add more to your page (or whatever it is) thus unchecking ALL checkboxes may be incorrect or wrong.

Either specify a class for each of the checkbox's involeved or you can use this to limit the operation to a given container

```
$(".example_container").find("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", "disabled")
```

Comment: I got it $("#multiselectelement").multiselect("widget").find(':checkbox').attr('disabled'‌​,'true');

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", "disabled")
```

Comment: $("#multiselectelement").multiselect("widget").find(':checkbox').attr('disabled'‌​,'true');

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: I got it $("#multiselectelement").multiselect("widget").find(':checkbox').attr('disabled','true');

Answer (score 0):

use

```
  $("input:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```